# what is the right form of the verb "lay" or "lies"

Tags: verbs, lie-lay-lain-laid

What is the right form of the verb in the following sentence?

> The essence of the brilliant outcome {**lay** / **lies**} in the excellence of the team.

I think **lies** is right (third person singular adds an s), but I read "lay" in the writing source.

Comment: If you have a source, kindly provide the link and add the context as well.

Comment: Both are correct; they refer to different times. *Lay* is the past tense of *lie*, and past-tense verbs are not inflect for persons or number.

Comment: "Lay" is Past Indefinite (2-nd form) of the irregular verb "Lie".  StoneyB beat me to the punch.

Comment: I too was about to post the same thing... man English is really not very good with some of the plural forms.

Comment: My comment should read "**do** not inflect for".

Comment: Lies sounds better but I think there both technically correct.

Comment: It needs more context to properly answer this. Both are correct in their own right but in my mind it depends whether the sentence is referring to the team, or to the outcome

Answer (score 3):

*Lay* and *lie* are two words with confusing forms (in real life people get these wrong all the time):

```
                                 present    past    past part.   -ing form

to lay - to put something down   lay(s)     laid    laid         laying
to lie - to rest or recline      lie(s)     lay     lain         lying
```

The way you are using it, you mean *to lie* (you can say "the brilliant outcome rests in the team's excellence", for example), so you want to use the present form of the verb, which is *lies* - *if* your sentence is describing something in the present:

> The essence of the brilliant outcome *lies* in the excellence of the team.

If you were expressing this in past tense, you'd say

> The essence of the brilliant outcome *lay* in the excellence of the team.

[Reference](http://www.chompchomp.com/rules/irregularrules02.htm).

Comment: You should use the definition of *lie* that fits the usage in the question, as it is different from what you cited "to rest or recline".

Comment: To clarify, the *lies* sentence sounds like it is a general aphorism: if you have a good team, good outcomes follow (see [gnomic aspect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gnomic_aspect)). The *lay* sentence sounds like it describes a specific event: we had a good team, and thus we obtained a good outcome.